# How to enlarge manually LineLegend and how to make them according to the line (Dashed or continuous)

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have attached a picture of a graph which I obtained by combining three plots obtained named them plot1, plot2 and plot3. I have used the following code for combining these plots:

```
Show[plot1, plot2, plot3, PlotRange -> Automatic, Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["Number of iterates", Black, Small],Style["Absolute error", Black, Small]}, 
Epilog ->Inset[LineLegend[{Red, Cyan, Black}, {"New", "Newton","Modified  Newton"}], {8, 0.020}]]
```

I have obtained the following image
[image]

Now I want to enlarge manually or automatically New, Newton and Modified newton inside the image. Also the lines with New, Newton and Modified newton are straight and smoth. I want to make them according to the dashes as the plotted lines.

Comment: `LineLegend[{Red, Cyan, Black}, Style[#, 16] & /@ {"New", "Newton", "Modified  Newton"}]`. Not sure what you mean by "I want to make them according to the dashes as the plotted lines".

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi I think that the idea here is to have matching `PlotStyle` between each curve and its associated `LineLegend`

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide code for the plots explicitly I chose to plot some toy functions.

```
frame[xx_] := Framed[xx, FrameStyle -> {Black, Thickness[.1]}];
Plot[{x, x^2, x^3}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, AbsoluteThickness[3]}, {Cyan, Dashed, 
    AbsoluteThickness[3]}, {Dashing[Tiny], Thickness[.01], Black}}, 
 Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Number of iterates", Black, Small], 
   Style["Absolute error", Black, Small]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[
   LineLegend[{Style["New", 17], Style["Newton", 17], 
     Style["Modified Newton", 17]}, LegendFunction -> frame], {.8, 
    0.5}], ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image: plot]

Edit: another -equivalent- way of writing the above is the following:

```
Plot[{x, x^2, x^3}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, AbsoluteThickness[3]}, {Cyan, Dashed, 
    AbsoluteThickness[3]}, {Dashing[Tiny], Thickness[.01], Black}}, 
 Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Number of iterates", Black, Small], 
   Style["Absolute error", Black, Small]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Style["New", 17], Style["Newton", 17], 
     Style["Modified Newton", 17]}, 
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, 
        FrameStyle -> {Black, Thickness[.1]}] &)], {.8, 0.5}], 
 ImageSize -> 700]
```

If you do not wish the `LineLegend` to be framed just remove the following from the above commands:

```
LegendFunction -> frame
```

or

```
LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameStyle -> {Black, Thickness[.1]}] &)
```

depending if you like the former or the latter better.